# How to dynamically traverse through all fields of a class in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to dynamically traverse through all fields of a class in kotlin. The purpose is that I'd like to convert the class object to TSV by joining all fields. As there will be a lot of subclasses, it would be great to do this dynamically. After some investigation, I found a solution below. It did work but the order of the fields is not consistent with the order each field was declared.

I think annotation could work, but not sure how. Any idea? Thanks!

```
abstract class BaseModel {
    fun toTSV(): String {
        return this::class.memberProperties.map {
            it.getter.call(this).toString()
        }.joinToString("\t")
    }
}
class Model (
    val model_id: String,
    val name: String,
    val version: Int,
    val desc: String
) : BaseModel()


fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val model = Model(
            model_id = "mid",
            name = "model name",
            version = 1,
            desc = "some desc"
    )
    println(model.toTSV())
}
```

The code above produces:

```
some_desc   mid model_name  1
```

but I am expecting:

```
mid  model_name  1   some_desc
```

Just like the order of fields in the class.

Comment: May be a good idea to use some ordering, alphabetical for example, to guarantee a fixed order.

Comment: I wouldn't do this myself; I'd look at using a library such as Jackson, which is all set up for serialising object data.  Or, if you need that sort of access, consider using a Map instead of object fields.  As we have to say quite often, reflection should be a last resort: it's slow, ugly, fragile, and error-prone — useful for frameworks and plug-ins, but a real code smell for most apps.

Comment: Does Jackson support TSV actually? I knew it support CSV though @gidds

Comment: @user3672968 I haven't checked Jackson specifically; but CSV is an underspecified format and generally supports a range of separators, not just commas (despite the name).  (The Apache Commons CSV library does, for example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using generics and extension properties we can achieve this like so

```
val <T> T.fields: List<String>
    get() {
        return this!!::class.java.declaredFields.map { it.name }
    }

val <T> T.fieldsString: String
    get() {
        return this!!::class.java.declaredFields.map { it.name }.joinToString(", ")
    }



 fun toTSV2(): String {
    val name2value = this::class.memberProperties.map {
        it.name to it.getter.call(this).toString()
    }.toMap()
    return this!!::class.java.declaredFields.map { 
        name2value[it.name] }.joinToString("\t")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! With your suggestion, I could indeed get the field list with the same order as they were declared. However, I need to get the values of these fields and make them TSV. Any ideas on how to get the value for each field with the field name dynamically?

Comment: One idea is that, I can use this!!::class.java.declaredFields to sort this::class.memberProperties and then I can use it.getter.call(this).toString() to get the value for the field. Not sure if there is any better solution though

Comment: Looks like this idea worked. Posting whole solution below. Thanks!

Comment: edit your answer to be more relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to override toString on each model, to get the tab separated values in each field :)

```
class MyModel {
var id: Long = 0L
...
override fun toString(): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    sb.append("class MyModel {\n")
    sb.append("    id: ").append(toIndentedString(id)).append("\n")
    sb.append("\n}")
    return sb.toString()
    }
    
    /**
     * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
     * (except the first line).
     */
    private fun toIndentedString(o: Any?): String {
        return o?.toString()?.replace("\n", "\n    ") ?: "null"
    }

}
```

this works for me everytime.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, but we need to manually define the format of the output for each field, I am wondering if we can achieve this dynamically and programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

OK, combined with Brandon's answer, I finally got this. It worked:

```
    fun toTSV2(): String {
    val name2value = this::class.memberProperties.map {
        it.name to it.getter.call(this).toString()
    }.toMap()
    return this!!::class.java.declaredFields.map { 
        name2value[it.name] }.joinToString("\t")
}
```